# Corda node started but not interacting with other nodes

Tags: corda

I have modifed the node.conf file for node2 and **ONLY** added sshd { port = 2222 } in node.conf file.
after that restarted the node2.

my node2 started but it is not accepting any request from other nodes.
also not performing any action , because if node1 who is sending request to node2 then there is no request comming at node2 and at node1 it has 1 or 2 checkpoints.

and i am stuck here , Please help to resolve issue.

all node1 , node2 , notary is running fine. issue is only with node2 not accepting any request from node1.

although i can see in node1 logs that its connected to node2.

i observed my node2 do not have logs like in other nodes 
[Node thread-1] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.createQueueIfAbsent - Start bridge for previously empty queue internal.peers

Using corda OS 4.0
please help.

Comment: So what happens if you revert `node.conf` to what it used to be before the problem happened? Also do you see any errors inside `cordapps/logs/`?

Comment: No change after reverting and no error in logs .  Node starts Successfully .. but does not accept any requests

Comment: Can you add the "node.conf" contents of node1 and node2, to your question?

Comment: There isn't enough info to answer this question objectively and is more of a generic question about how to investigate/debug issues.

Answer (score 0):

For the connection issue, check if one or more of your Java processes are still running thus utilizing the connection, this conflict would mean that the newly started process cannot reestablish an already established connection so it is normal that it fails and the logs you see are from the pre-existing connection.

Before you run your node(s) make sure to kill any running processes with:
`kill -9 <PID>` where PID is the *process id* of the node running

or if you want to kill all Java processes running in your environment:
`killall -9 java`

For the second issue which you mentioned, that node2 does not have logs, if you are running the nodes manually from the command line with the command `java -jar corda.jar` make sure to run the command from the same directory where corda.jar is.

Wrong-way to run the node:
`java -jar /path/to/jar/corda.jar`

The proper way to run the node:

- go to the same directory `cd /path/to/jar/`
- run the command `java -jar corda.jar`

This StackOverflow question might help as a reference:
[Does the Thread still exist if the JVM crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477803/does-the-thread-still-exist-if-the-jvm-crashes)

Comment: all my nodes started successfully without any issues and errors. only the problem is node2 is not receiving any transaction requests from node1.